# Perform binary encoding on a string column with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sheet like this.

```
 taglist
0  1|2|3
1  2|3|4


taglist = DataFrame(taglist.str.split('|',expand = True))
```

I can convert it to:

```
    0     1     2  
0   1     2     3
1   2     3     4
```

But, I want it like this:
The same number in the same column and using Onehotencoder.

```
      1   2   3  4
0     1   1   1  0
1     0   1   1  1
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple encoding problem, you can use `str.get_dummies` to do this:

```
df['taglist'].str.get_dummies(sep='|')

   1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
```

Or, building on `str.split`, we may also use

```
split = df['taglist'].str.split('|', expand=True)
pd.get_dummies(split, prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(level=0, axis=1)

   1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
```

Comment: @lay Found a better solution for you. Thanks.